# UIWebView loading but not displaying content

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ipod

UIWebView successfully loaded content, but is not displaying it. UIWebView is just white screen. BUT, if you click on this UIWebView it will process your click. For example, **if you click at place where the link should be (but in fact the white space), the click processed and next page loaded and displayed OK**.

The bug is unstable. I got it only with local HTML file (our homepage, it generated locally), web content loads OK. It happens in 20% cases. But in the same time, it is very sticky. Once got white screen, you can reload this page many times and see white screen (but if you click on invisible link, another page displayed successfully). Sometimes it occasionally appears without any reason. Your can "scroll" this blank screen up and down and it occasionally loaded. This local HTML has a lot of stuff, embedded images, javascripts, etc, and it could be javascript problem, but I can't explain how it can be, that content invisible, but still clickable.

It happens in iPod real device and iPhone simulator 4.3, but can't reproduce it on iPad or iPad simulator.

I spent a whole day trying resolve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this!

This really weird behaviour of UIWebView was caused by javascript code. The javascript was like (simplified):

```
    <script>

    function onLoad() {
       location.href='xxx://pageLoaded';
    }

    </script>

<body onload='onLoad();'>
```

The idea of this code was to inform app about the fact that page was loaded. In the app I catch request to xxx://pageLoaded and cancel it (in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`). Because request cancellation, I didn't expect any problems here. Espesially, I didn't expect that content will become invisible, but still clicable. I added timer (`setTimeout`) between `onload` fires and `location.href` change. It solves the problem.

NOTE: I know about `webViewDidFinishLoad` event in `UIWebView`. This is very simplified example just to explain the problem and the solution. Real javascript is more sophisticated and what it is doing can't be reached by simple use `webViewDidFinishLoad`.